# Why does my JavaScript code fail the test case I am running?

Tags: javascript, testcase

I am still a newbie in programming, and I decided to take up The Odin Project course. I decided to make my own code and see if it works, but so far, I am having errors with this specific problem.

Here is the code I made by myself.

```js
 const removeFromArray = function(array,...toDelete) {
    const newArray=[];

    array.forEach(item=>{
        if(item != toDelete){
            newArray.push(item);
        }
    })
    return newArray; };

// Do not edit below this line 

module.exports = removeFromArray;
```

And this is the test case I am currently running it by. My code passes the first test case but it fails in the second. Can someone help me understand why? I am pretty sure it has something to do with my if statement but I don't entirely understand why it does not work.

```js
describe('removeFromArray', () => {
  test('removes a single value', () => {
    expect(removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4], 3)).toEqual([1, 2, 4]);
  });
  test('removes multiple values', () => {
    expect(removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4], 3, 2)).toEqual([1, 4]);
  });
});
```

Comment: Your `toDelete` parameter will be an **array** of values, so none of the individual values will ever be equal to the whole array.

Comment: toDelete is an Array since you defined the parameter as `...toDelete`

Comment: But in that case shouldn't my code also fail in the first test case where it only removes one number? Or does my code only read one element in the whole toDelete array?

Comment: @buckwheat your first testcase passes because of the loose equality check (`!=` instead of `!==`). Both operands will be converted to strings (`[3].toString(); --> "3"`) so `"3" == "3"` yields `true`. But in the second case this does not work since `[3, 2].toString(); --> "3,2"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this

```
item != toDelete
```

toDelete is an array and you are comparing it with a number

you should search for item inside toDelete instead

```
!toDelete.includes(item)
```

The reason why it works with the first example is because, in javascript, 4 == [4] returns true. Your code would not have worked at all if you used === instead of ==.